# bootstrap contextmenu not working for dynamic created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on family tree building. here i want is. when i made right click on element contextmenu should appear. but in my code it's not working properly.

context menu is working only on static elements not for dynamic element.

```
$(function() {
    $('span').contextmenu({

        target: '#context-menu2',
        onItem: function (context, e) {
          alert($(e.target).text());
        }
      });
});

    <div id="wrapper">
            <span class="label toggleable nodeContextMenu" data-toggle="context" id="root">Sale Person</span>
            <div class="branch lv1"><div class="entry sole">    
               <span data-toggle="context" id="childNode" class="label wordwrap level1 nodeContextMenu selectedDiv" title="sdsd">sdsd</span>

           </div>

   </div>
```

when i click on span element new element is created under span element but context menu is not working on this. new element is same as parent span element. how can i bind context menu for new element

Comment: Have you tried formatting your code and cleaning JS/HTML errors? You have a `]` where you should have a `}`, also, you're referring to an non-existing id `#context-menu2`

Comment: that's by mistake added

Comment: also i have tried demos by google. and i created another element at run time,  demo example are also not working